# Thread safe work with boost::asio timers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a question about boost asio timers and safe-thread work with them. Let's say, i have the following class:

CTest.h:

```
class CTest
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;

    void Check();
    CTest ();

    ~CTest ();
};
```

And CTest.cpp:

```
CTest::CTest():
timer (io, boost::posix_time::seconds(0))
{
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CTest::Check, this));
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
}

void CTest::Check()
{
    //some work

    m_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CTest::Check, this));

}

CTest::~CTest()
{
     io.stop();
}
```

So, the question is how to finish Check thread safe? I mean, this Check function can be called after destructor, and we have a crash.

Answer (score 2):

Using io_service::stop() is very rarely what you want to do.

A few points:

- Keep the thread object around, and call thread.join() to make sure it is complete.
- Don't call io.stop(), call m_timer.cancel() then m_thread.join() to clean up.
- Consider using shared_ptr and weak_ptr to manage object lifetime more cleanly (ie: bind a weak_ptr instance into your async_wait callback rather than a bare `this`. In the callback function, convert the weak_ptr to a shared_ptr and if that is valid then call the method.
- m_timer wil be used from multiple threads, you need to manage access using a mutex.

Just a few points. Not going to rewrite your code for you.

Comment: Considering your 3rd suggestion, do think `std::enable_shared_from_this` could be useful here?

Comment: @snow_abstraction Not for that technique because destroying the object will also destroy the inherited data members from `enable_shared_from_this` meaning you cannot check for validity.

Answer (score 1):

Your destructor should stop all timers, so they will not be called after object is destroyed: `m_timer.cancel()`. Also, if you want to prevent simultaneous methods calls on same object, wrap your **boost::bind** with **boost::asio::strand::wrap**. Check out asio documentation for examples.